# Why java virtual machines?

Tags: java

I know that java virtual machine make things easier by making our code system independent.But the thing I don't understand is why cannot we use compilers for each platform just like Jvms for each platform??I mean there are Jvms which are system dependent.So why cant we write system dependent compilers instead of Jvms.If it is better and easier to write Jvm than compiler ,in what way it is???
I am sorry if there is anything wrong in my question .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The compiler is not platform specific. That's the job of the JVM, not for compiler. But! there are Java compilers that generate bytecode that can perform better than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the type of language it is (Interpreted vs Compiled).  A compiler goes (more or less) from human readable to computer readable (system dependent).  Java and other similar languages like .NET/C# go from human readable to bytecode, (always readable to the virtual machine), and from there are translated by the virtual machine to that particular computer's computer readable code.  The whole point is to build once, use everywhere.  When you use a compiler, it must be compiled for every system type individually.